# Covering screw holes in hardwood floor

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, squeak

I have an old hardwood floor that is squeaky. I'm using this product: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C6YDMGGK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C6YDMGGK)

to drill 1/8 inch holes in the floor, then driving the special screws in, that break a little bit under the floor level. My question is about covering those holes. Since the floor is finished, I'm using wood putty instead of wood filler. The problem is that it doesn't look good (see images) and doesn't fully harden. Compare the covered nail holes in the image, to the larger and ugly screw hole I covered.

I did not find a product or idea that can cover those holes nicely, so my entire project is on hold at the moment. Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wiping some stain on the filler?

Comment: I have not, I think so far my favorite idea is matching the wood grain with putty + markers, then applying some semi-glossy finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually take one of two approaches when it comes to this.

The first is the most tedious.  It involves buying two Minwax wood stain finish markers and manually staining your wood putty to match the grain.  You can make this method look amazing by mixing your own wood putty using fine and medium grain sawdust with clear gorilla glue instead of using prebought stuff, this gives it that nice gloss finish without the need for sealant.  This method is very time consuming as you can imagine, but if looks are a major sticking point, I recommend going ahead and investing the time.

The other method works best for darker colored woods, and I think yours is just dark enough for it to work well.  First pick up a half gallon of polyurethane, a model paintbrush, and small container of cheap activated carbon:

[image: Activated Carbon]

The example in the image is from [Hobby Lobby](https://www.hobbylobby.com/Crafts-Hobbies/Candle-Soap-Making/Lotion-Beauty-Products/Activated-Charcoal/p/80933310) and costs $2.99 USD.  Wood Filler goes in first, followed by a very light dusting of activated carbon, and use a small paintbrush to apply the polyurethane sealant in the direction of the wood grain. if it's too dark, dip your brush back into the polyurethane and apply another layer to dilute the amount of activated carbon.

Sadly, I do not have any example images of this method.  But luckily, it's also not expensive to test.  Give your test spots 4 days to cure before you decide on whether or not to do the entire room.  For better results, open the activated carbon and remove the film and leave it exposed in the room you're using it in for 48 hours prior to use to acclimate. This will reduce post-cure bubble formation.

Answer (score 4):

A standard 90's method would be wood dowels, AKA wooden discs. They may come as a beam you cut to pieces.

- You take a larger drill sized for the dowels and make a recess so the screw head hides fully in the wood with some space to spare.
- You put in the screw.
- Then hammer in the wood disk. Remember to align the grain correctly. If it sticks out, sandpaper it to flatness. Result will be almost untouched wooden surface, if you pick correct color of the wood.

This is how the furniture makers fixed knotholes in planks in the old days - if you inspect very old furniture made from actual planks, you'll find some spots with wooden circles - either screws, or repairs of knotholes.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! These are also called "plugs". I actually have a set of "plug cutters" that I can use to cut plugs from a scrap of wood that I'm using to make a project so that my plugs match the wood being used.

Comment: The problem is that dowels would be cut against the grain (so what's exposed is end grain).